# Change the column order in a table for a subclassed model

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

In a situation where you have a subclassed model in peewee, how do you tell peewee what order to create the columns in the table? In the following example, the order is "b, c, a", but I want "a, b, c".

```
class BaseModel(Model):
  b = CharField()
  c = CharField()

class Table(BaseModel):
  a = CharField()

database.create_table(Table)
```

The order matters because this is for a sandbox area of our product where we test new changes. The UI is very generic, but users still need to be able use the product so having some usability enhancements such as column order is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When peewee creates a table, it [calls `get_fields`](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/3690bbaeef18c36d5bd60156c57ac86777c23d36/peewee.py#L1779), which calls [`get_sorted_fields`](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/3690bbaeef18c36d5bd60156c57ac86777c23d36/peewee.py#L3755), which uses the [`_sort_key`](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/3690bbaeef18c36d5bd60156c57ac86777c23d36/peewee.py#L725) of each field, which is based on the order the fields are defined.  A field in a subclass is defined after a field in the parent class, so it will sort lower.

The only way to change the order that the columns will be created in the table is to subclass `Field` or `ModelOptions` (and `BaseModel` to use the subclassed `ModelOptions`, etc.), override the relevant code to apply a different sort order, and use your new subclasses everywhere.

A more practical and maintainable solution is to just maintain a list on the side that names the columns in the order you want, then send that to the frontend to tell it how to display the columns.  When you add a new column, simply add it in the correct order in that list as well.