# Peewee How to change order of fields which are declared in a BaseModel?

Tags: python, peewee

In my BaseModel I like to add `creation_date` and `last_updated_date` so I don't have to type it on every model:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    creation_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    last_updated_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(BaseModel):
    email = CharField(max_length=64)

db.create_tables([User])
```

The problem with this is that it will create the table with the `creation_date`/`last_updated_date` columns first.

```
create table user(id serial, creation_date timestamp, last_updated_date timestamp, email varchar2(64));
```

This becomes a minor inconvenience when you use psql or an IDE to query your data. I prefer the non-ID metadata to be on the right most side of the screen, not the left.

Is there anyway to override this behavior such that I can have the `creation_date`/`last_updated_date` columns created last?

```
create table user(id serial, email varchar2(64), creation_date timestamp, last_updated_date timestamp);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the column order in a table for a subclassed model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036817/change-the-column-order-in-a-table-for-a-subclassed-model)